# Python 3 tkinter notepad Cut and Copy

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I'm trying to make a notepad written in python using tkinter. I'm having trouble making the edit menu work. I'm currently trying to implement copy, cut, and paste but I'm having issues. When I try to press the cut button I get a message like this "TypeError: cut() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'event'" I'm honestly new to the whole class thing in Python so this is my first attempt at using that. I've shortened my code for convenience. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class Notepad:

    #Functions
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Text.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copy)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cut)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)

    def copy(self, event=None):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        text = self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.clipboard_append(text)

    def cut(self, event):
        self.copy()
        self.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

    def paste(self, event):
        text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        self.insert('insert', text)

    root = Tk()
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    root.title('Written in Python')
    root.minsize(width=100, height=100)
    root.geometry('800x500+350+150') #Height, Width, X, Y coordinates of the program

    #NotePad
    textArea = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, width=1000, height=100) 
    #Height and width of notepad
    textArea.pack()

    root = Tk()
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    editMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
    editMenu.add_separator()
    editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=cut)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `cut` is defined with two arguments: `self` and `event`, but the menu command invokes `cut()` without argument, hence the error message.

In addition, your class structure looks strange to me, especially putting the last block of code directly in the class, not inside a class methods. I suggest you to create instead a `Notepad` class inheriting from `Text` (or `ScrolledText`), with your custom methods and bindings and put the `root = Tk() ...` outside the class, like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class Notepad(ScrolledText):

    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        ScrolledText.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copy)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cut)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)

    def copy(self, event=None):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        text = self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.clipboard_append(text)

    def cut(self, event=None):
        self.copy()
        self.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

    def paste(self, event=None):
        text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        self.insert('insert', text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    menu = tk.Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    root.title('Written in Python')
    root.minsize(width=100, height=100)
    root.geometry('800x500+350+150') #Height, Width, X, Y coordinates of the program

    #NotePad
    notepad = Notepad(root, width=1000, height=100) 
    #Height and width of notepad
    notepad.pack()

    editMenu = tk.Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
    editMenu.add_separator()
    editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=notepad.cut)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=notepad.copy)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=notepad.paste)

    root.mainloop()
```

In the above code, the functions `cut`, `copy` and `paste` are methods of the `Notepad` class, you can invoke them with `notepad.cut(event)`. Since, you don't use the `event` argument in the methods, it is just here for the binding, I suggest you to do `def cut(self, event=None)` so that `event` becomes optional, with default value `None`. This way you can directly use `notepad.copy` as a command in the `editMenu`.